# Is there any other way to store data in c except in a text file or csv file?

Tags: c

~Lately , I've been struggling a lot w/ file handling in c  ,is there any other way to store data in c?

I'm working on a project that analyze company's stocks for you, so in that ,

~firstly I've to store password , name , no. of stocks  ,company name , no of shares of each company , price of each share , total .

~Secondly ,  if the user wants to see his/her portfolio ,he/she  has to insert the password and I'll compare that password w/ previously inserted passwords of users and then show his/her portfolio.

Thirdly , if the user want to delete any specific company's stock .

And currently , i'm on the second part where I've to display portfolio .
I'm using fscanf to read the data , but sometimes it didn't stop at the end of file and also I don't how to correctly read lines with it.

Comment: What kind of data? What are the issues you are having? If you can describe those, ideally with a [mcve], perhaps we can assist.

Comment: You can also store in binary files. Or JSON, XML, etc. It all depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C, you can store your data in `binary` or `text` formats. CSV, JSON, XML, atom, et al are all `text` files with some syntax and semantics, that is all. C has all abilities to store in whichever format you desire. Read about the various IO functions, like `fscanf`, `fread`, etc.